# Why did highlight all sidebar menu items in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and I have bootstrap sidemenu items,   like this

```
<li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'reports', 0,7)}}">
    <a href="{{route('reports.alluser')}}">All Users</a></li>

    <li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'reports', 0,7)}}">
    <a href="{{route('reports.pie_chart')}}">Category Chart</a></li>

    <li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'reports', 0,7)}}">
    <a href="{{route('reports.categorystatic')}}">Category Static</a></li>
```

I have helper function for this sidemenu in app/helper/Helper.php

```
<?php

if(! function_exists('active_menu')) {
    function active_menu($currentRouteName, $requestName, $start, $finish){
        if (substr($currentRouteName,$start, $finish) == $requestName){
            return 'active';

        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    }
```

but when I click one menu link above highlight all menu links. problem is here in the all links, it is highlight all menu witch include 'reports', 0,7

```
'reports', 0,7
```

How can I prevent highlighting all menu items and highlighting only selected menu item?

how can I fix this problem here?

Comment: No, any answer...?

Comment: You should use a unique id for each menu and highlight by id rather than a class.

Comment: @Jamie_D How can I do this as your comments